# How to set Word Application as owner of WinForm in Add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I am working with Add-ins in Word. on ribbon button click, I open a WinForm using

```
Forms.frmFontCheck _form = new Forms.frmFontCheck(); _form.ShowDialog();
```

when I check its owner on _form Load Event, it is NULL.

I tried setting owner using [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f83584a5-0a7b-4471-a109-00c009aa9602/microsoft-word-ribbon-becomes-unresponsive-with-a-document-open-in-a-web-browser-control) but still owner is null.

Also since owner is null, sometimes Word goes to background and another application opens and _form opens on top of another application.

So main thing is how to set ribbon as owner of _form?